# How to pre type array of React Elements in typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

```
import { Button, ButtonGroup } from '@material-ui/core';
let buttons: React.Component[] = [];
```

returns: Type 'Element' is missing the following properties from type 'Component<{}, {}, any>': context, setState, forceUpdate, render, and 2 more.  TS2740

```
let buttons: Buttons[] = [];
```

returns: 'Button' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.  TS2749

What is the correct way to declare a typed array of React Elements?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A fellow developer at my company informed me:

```
let buttons: JSX.Element[] = [];
```